# GDPR collecting vs storing

Tags: gdpr

I have a website that stores no personal data, however it does use ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), a code that scans the IP address of visitors, but the IP address isn't stored anywhere. It's only scanned to automatically select the language for the site.

Personally I wouldn't call it "collecting" since IP address isn't stored anywhere, so I'm wondering how GDPR views it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDPR views it as processing personal data.

Comment: That makes sense. However, if the data is not collected, what becomes of right of data portability? Can a visitor exercise that right even though there's no data to send  back?